# How to run a simple query using Informatica PowerCenter

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have never used Informatica PowerCenter before and just don't know where to begin.  To summarize my goal, I need to run a simple count query against a Teradata database using Informatica PowerCenter.  This query needs to be ran on a specific day, but doesn't require me to store or manipulate the data returned.  Looking at Informatica PowerCenter Designer is a bit daunting to me as I'm not sure what to be looking for.
Any help is greatly appreciated in understanding how to setup (if needed):

- Sources
- Targets
- Transformations
- Mappings

Is a transformation the only way to query data using PowerCenter?  I've looked at a lot of tutorials, but most seem to be oriented to familiar users.

Comment: What is the purpose of this query you want to run? To fetch data, a source and source qualifier is usually used, for looking things up you use a lookup transformation, to run more ad-hoc queries a SQL transformation is used.

Comment: It's a query on the number of tables in the DB.  The result of the query isn't really important as I just need to verify that the query can be performed against the database from Informatica for testing purposes.

Comment: As @Samik mentioned you can do this using various ways. You can also create a separate source and target for your teradata db. Use the SQL override for the source and do your operation there. Then you can use Target Load plan to prioritise that Source->Target flow. In case the connectivity isn't there, the whole session will fail. But if you want to do the operation in the middle of your flow, use SQL Transformation.

Comment: Informatica is NOT a scheduler that should be used for executing queries at certain intervals, like pinging a database. It's possible, but it's not the purpose of the tool - and it's not good at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a query against a database using informatica, only if you create a mapping, session and workflow to run that. But you cannot see the result unless you store it somewhere, either in a flatfile or a table. 
Here are the steps to create it anyway.

1. Import your source table in source analyzer from Teradata.
2. Create a flat file target or import a relational target in target analyzer
3. Create a mapping m_xyz, drag and drop your source into the mapping.
4. You will see your source and source qualifier in the mapping. Write your custom query in source qualifier, say select count(*) as cnt from table
5. Remove all the ports from SQ except one numeric port from source to SQ and name it as cnt, count from your select will be assigned to this port.
6. Now drag and drop this port to an expression transformation.
7. Drag and drop your target into the mapping
8. Propagate the column from expression to this flat file/relational target.
9. Create a workflow and a session for this mapping.
10. In workflow you can schedule it to run on specific date.
11. When you execute this, count will be loaded into the column of that flat file or table.